# FastLED, how can i change the Number of LEDs (NUM_LEDS) at runtime?

Tags: c++, arduino, led, fastled

is it possible to change the number of leds at runtime (Arduino/FastLED) ?
How can i do that?

A small sample code would be nice because i am a newbie :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The FastLED library has an AddLeds function for adding additional LED strips at runtime, but it doesn't seem to know how to forget about LEDs or change them after the fact. You should define your FastLED array to the maximum number of LEDs you plan to connect. You can then keep track of how many LEDs you really want to control in a variable which you can use in place of the NUM_LEDS constant.